# 3D Axes with break in matplotlib/pylab

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

I want to create a 3D plot in matplotlib and since I have some outliers in my data, I would like to create a break in my X-axis.

This is quite easy to do in a 2D plot:- a> You create two subplots sharing either of the axes b> Switch off the appropriate ticks/spines c> Manipulate the hspace between the plots to make them appear closer. However, I cannot implement this in a 3D plot where the primary problem seems to be getting the two plots to align with themselves.

There might be a completely different way to do this in a 3D plot or may be somehow manipulate the subplots to get the effect of a broken axis.